# python coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python, unicode

Hello I am new to python and programming. I am trying to make a organizing app.  I am getting this error but don't know what it means

```
import os, glob, shutil, sys, time

#source is the location of the directory
src = os.listdir("/Users/user/Downloads")
dst = os.listdir("/Users/user/Documents/Media")
for filename in os.listdir(src):
    if os.stat(filename).st_mtime < now - 240 * 86400:
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            if files.endswith(".mkv"):
                shutil.move(source, destination)
```

this is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    for filename in os.listdir(src):
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Comment: So what error are you getting? (Show the entire traceback, please.)

Comment: `src` is a list. You are sending it to `os.listdir`, which expects a string.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    for filename in os.listdir(src):
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Comment: BTW There should an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40075952/edit) link below the question, which you can use to add relevant details to the question.

Comment: @zvone how can i fix, can show a example. this only been learning python for week.

Comment: Either `src = "/Users/user/Downloads"` or `for filename in src`. Former makes more sense. Don't call `os.listdir` and then call `os.listdir` again on the result of the first call.